# Javascript date validation - prefixing 19 (century) to two digit date

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I am doing some validations with `Date()` and I have noticed that if I create a invalid date with a two digit year instead of four `Date(01/01/55)` then the current century will be prefixed onto the year - 55 becomes 1955 - instead of a invalid date object that I can test with NaN.

This is a problem because I allow users to enter dates without any '/', then I create the date using `substr`:

```
            // Check date is in correct format
            var fDate = val.split('/');
            // Should have 3 parts
            if (fDate.length != 3) {
                var day = val.substr(0, 2);
                var month = val.substr(2, 2);
                var year = val.substr(4, 4);

                val = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
                control.val(val);
            }
```

So if the user enters `010155` my logic turns it into `01/01/55` then `Date()` creates the date `01/01/1955`, but instead I want it to create an invalid date object.

Comment: You probably should do your own validation -- unfortunately, there's inconsistencies in the way non-standard date formats are handled by browsers.

Comment: Maybe it is a good choice to use a lib like http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay well I developed a solution that does what I'm happy with. momentjs.com seems great, and I probably could of used it, but I am using the jqueryui.com Datepicker which uses `Date` and I want the use to be able to enter dates with no year, 1 or 2 number years, which defaults to the beginning of this century.

```
 var cYear = new Date().getFullYear();
                    var c = cYear.toString().substr(0, 2);

                    day = val.substr(0, 2);
                    if (day > 31) {
                        leftOverD = day.charAt(1);
                        day = "0" + day.charAt(0);
                    } else if (day.length == 1) {
                        day = "0" + day;
                    } else if (day.length == 0) {
                        day = "01";
                    }

                    month = (leftOverD) ? leftOverD + val.charAt(2) : val.substr(2, 2);
                    if (month > 12) {
                        leftOverM = month.charAt(1);
                        month = "0" + month.charAt(0);
                    } else if (month.length == 1) {
                        month = "0" + month;
                    } else if (month.length == 0) {
                        month = "01";
                    }

                    var strYear;
                    if (leftOverD && leftOverM) {
                        strYear = val.substr(2, 4);
                    } else if (leftOverD || leftOverM) {
                        strYear = val.substr(3, 4);
                    } else if (!leftOverD && !leftOverM) {
                        strYear = val.substr(4, 4);
                    }

                    year = strYear;
                    if (year.length == 0) {
                        year = c + "00";
                    } else if (year.length == 1) {
                        var nYear = c + '0' + year;
                        if (nYear > cYear)
                            nYear = (c - 1) + '0' + year

                        year = nYear;
                    } else if (year.length == 2) {
                        var nYear = c + year;
                        if (nYear > cYear)
                            nYear = (c - 1) + year

                        year = nYear;
                    }
```

ps. Working with dates in JS is a nightmare. Why not simply have a `Date()` constructor that accepts a culture?